# Changing Javascript tabs with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website that's implementing tabs via javascript, and I'd like to create a button that goes to the 'next' tab.  I don't care if I have to hardcode in the tab IDs into the javascript or what, but regardless I'd like to be able to advance the tabs.

EDIT3: Here's a jfiddle implementation of what I have.  I just want the next button to be able to advance the tabs similar to clicking on them.  Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/Cd5qb/

Here's the code I have for the current working tabs, without a button:

```
var tabContents = $(".tab_content").hide(), 
    tabs = $("ul.tabs li");

tabs.first().addClass("active").show();
tabContents.first().show();

tabs.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this), 
        activeTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
    if(!$this.hasClass('active')){
        $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        tabContents.hide().filter(activeTab).fadeIn();
    }
    return false;
});
```

So I'm trying to implement something similar to the tabs.click for a button, and here's what I've got so far:

```
var tabbtn = $(".tabbutton");
tabbtn.click(function() {
    var listItem = document.getElementById('tab2');
    var $this = $(this), 
        activeTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
    tabContents.hide().filter("#tab2").fadeIn();

    return false;
});
```

This will actually display the right tab's information, but it won't change which tab header is highlighted.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can we see your HTML?  Or perhaps an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Sorry about that!  I've added some sample HTML, I hope that helps!

Comment: Are you using `jQuery UI` tabs?  When do you call `.tabs`?

Comment: Correct, I believe so.

`var listItem = document.getElementById('tab2');`
`alert('Index: ' + $('article').index(listItem));`

will return 1 for the index correctly

Comment: I don't see a call to `.tabs` on any element anywhere.  I tried setting up your code in jsfiddle.net but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Using alerts to get some variable info, it seems that the tabbtn.click method has a different idea of which tabs are active compared to the actual tabs. - if they both use `activeTab=$this.find...`, the tabs.click knows which is the active tab, whereas the tabbtn.click has it as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$(".tabbutton").click(function(){
    var nextTab = parseInt($("li.active").attr("id"), 10) + 1;
    if(nextTab === 4){ nextTab = 1; }
    $("#"+nextTab).click();
});
```

and adding a numerical equivalent id to the li items?

Working fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gugahoi/Cd5qb/1/

**UPDATE:**

Ok, [here is the new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gugahoi/Cd5qb/2/) with only the button changing the tabs.

This is all the js:

```
var tabContents = $(".tab_content").hide(), 
    tabs = $("ul.tabs li");

tabs.first().addClass("active").show();
tabContents.first().show();

$(".tabbutton").click(function(){
    var nextTab = parseInt($("li.active").attr("id"), 10) + 1;
    if(nextTab === 4){ nextTab = 1; }
    tabs.removeClass("active");
    $("#"+nextTab).addClass("active");
    tabContents.hide();
    $("#tab"+nextTab).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

And this is the only update needed in the html:

```
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
    <li id="1"><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
    <li id="2"><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
    <li id="3"><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting - it works perfectly in the fiddle, but does nothing on my actual site.  Although I tried your code word-for-word - perhaps that might be why.

Also though... I'd like to remove the ability of the user to click the headers of the tabs.  So ideally.. the button is the only thing that navigates through the tabs.  It looks like you're calling the click function of the tabs?  If you have any ideas, that'd be great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated with your new requests.

Answer (score 0):

@ Gustavo Hoirisch: With your previous code I too did removed 'active' from 'tabContents' and was about to post. Anywayz grt job.